# Dual space of $H'$ of a Hilbert space is a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Here is my question.
Q7: Show that the dual space $H'$ of a Hilbert space $H$ is a Hilbert space with inner product defined by $$\langle f_z,f_v\rangle=\langle v,z\rangle$$where $f_z(x)=\langle x,z\rangle$

I have successfully proven that $H'$ is an inner product space. To prove $H'$ is a Hilbert space, here is my approach.

Proof: Since $H$ is an inner product space, by defining a norm $||z||=\sqrt{\langle z,z\rangle}$ on it for all $z\in H$, we obtain a normed space of $H$. By theorem, the dual space of a normed space $H$ is always a Banach space. Hence, $H'$ is complete. Also, $H'$ is an inner product space with the inner product defined by $$\langle f_z,f_v\rangle=\langle v,z\rangle$$  with the normed defined by $$||f_z||=\sqrt{\langle f_z,f_z\rangle}$$Therefore, $H'$ is a Hilbert space.

Is my proof correct? (I realise that if my way of proving is correct, then the condition of $H$ being a Hilbert space is redundant.)

Comment: If you can help yourself to the dual space being complete this exercise seems altogether redundant. Completeness follows directly, though, since $||z||=||f_z||$ and $H$ is complete.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: If you have a Cauchy sequence of functionals it corresponds to a Cauchy sequence of elements in $H$. Since the latter converges to an element so does the former (to the corresponding functional).

Comment: So, to prove this question, I have to prove again the inner product space is complete instead of trying to using the result that every dual space of normed space is a Banach spaces ?

Comment: That would make it more self-contained, one does not even need to know about Banach spaces to work with Hilbert spaces. Otherwise, it is proving something simple by using something more abstract and complex.